# Помогите с проектированием приложения на Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

есть модель, примерно такая:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ManyToManyField(Manufacturer)
    model = models.CharField()
    car_class = models.CharField()
    vin = models.IntegerField()
    color = models.CharField()
    year = models.DateField()
```

Естественно в базе может(и будет) много почти одинаковых машин, у одной модели будет отличаться будет только цвет и vin.

Хочется сделать доступ как к каждой отдельной машине так и к модели в общем, но без создания какой-нибудь CarModel. 
Вопрос: как правильно выбрать все машины у которых указана одна марка и модель? просто через sql, не логично если машин одной марки 100+ штук, то таким макаром же 100+ запросов и будет или нет?
или лучше создать модель типа CarModel с машины сделать на неё FK поле? или есть какой-то еще более логичный путь?)

в итоге хочется получить страничку типа: машина модели Б имеется в красном, черном, белом цвете, их vin 1, 2, 3... 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам подойдёт [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) модель базы данных. Для этого поребуется 3 таблицы. Базовая таблица с характеристиками, общими для всех автомобилей модели. Таблица харектиристик, в которой к id характеристики привязывается частный атрибут, например  "цвет красный" или "год 2009". И третья таблица, в которой идёт связь id-автомобиля к разным id-атрибутов.

Comment: не, слишком сложно для такой простой задачи. Проще тогда создать модель _CarModels_ и сделать из модели _Car_ на неё FK. и уже во вьюхе выбирать через [select-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Да, согласен, в подобной конструкции есть определенная сложность. Преймущество только в одном - если таблица характеристик будет общей для всех автомобилей, без относительно модели, можно будет искать "все красные машины" или "все машины 2009го года" более простым запросом.